# android opencv rgb to hsv

Tags: android, opencv

How to convert rgb to hsv and make the hsv display on the screen in opencv for android?

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_opencv_samples_tutorial3_Sample3View_FindFeatures(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jint width, jint height, jbyteArray yuv, jintArray bgra)
{
    jbyte* _yuv  = env->GetByteArrayElements(yuv, 0);
    jint*  _bgra = env->GetIntArrayElements(bgra, 0);

    Mat myuv(height + height/2, width, CV_8UC1, (unsigned char *)_yuv);
    Mat mbgra(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char *)_bgra);
    Mat mgray(height, width, CV_8UC1, (unsigned char *)_yuv);


    //Please make attention about BGRA byte order
    //ARGB stored in java as int array becomes BGRA at native level
    cvtColor(myuv, mbgra, CV_YUV420sp2BGR, 4);





    env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(bgra, _bgra, 0);
    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(yuv, _yuv, 0);
}

}
```

The above code gets input from the camera which is yuv and converts to rgb. I know I need to use cvtColor function to convert from rgb to hsv but what parameters the Mat for hsv should have? And how to make it display rather than rgb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HSV you should use 8 bits unsigned. I suppose your problem is with the Hue (which in theory should be between 0 and 360, but in openCV Hue is represented in the interval 0,180.

How to see this: I was looking at each of the 3 channels (H,S,V) as grey images. At the end, even after transformation the image is the same, just the way you represent the image is different.

Comment: i have same problem,, you got any solution?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to Convert RGB Mat image to HSV Color Space you can do like this :

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(src, dst, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV, 3); //3 is HSV Channel
```

Before you display it in Android Screen, you need to Convert HSV from 3 Channel to 4 Channel because Android cannot display Mat in 3 Channel. See [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-opencv/N3QU1SZd74E/PD3GROby6ggJ) for more Information. Code like this :

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(dst, src, Imgproc.COLOR_HSV2RGBA, 4); // 4 is RGBA Channel
```